# GridView pointToPosition with spacing

Tags: android, layout, gridview

My application uses gridview to display some items and I want some drag-drop in that gridview. Basically user can pick an item and move it to different position. That's not hard to implement but I've stumbled on a small problem. Which is `pointToPosition` returning `INVALID_POSITION` when the point is *between* two grid cells. Which is understandable but doesn't really help - in my case I'm showing user a preview of what the order will be as he is dragging stuff around and when he is dragging over the spacing I suddenly don't know what I should show.

One solution is to remove spacing actually. But I still want some visual spacing between tiles.

There's a chance I'm missing some way of calculating the closest tile to given position.

What would be the best way to have gridview with "visual-only" spacing between elements?

My current (temporary? final?) solution is not to use backgrounds at all and draw them directly into gridview background. This doesn't seem to be good idea though.

Comment: Can't you remove the spacing in the `GridView` and add it directly to its cell views directly?

Comment: Cell views are simple ImageViews. I am trying to avoid using something more complex than that.

Comment: Did you try to add some padding to the `ImageViews` themselves and removing the `GridView`'s spacing?

Comment: I needed also to make my ImageViews square (gridview sets width, I set to use same width), so I had to override the onMeasure. This could be the reason setting padding doesn't work - background is stretched to full view.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I'm going to use in the end: spacing = 0 and layer-list drawable containing shapedrawable with rounded corners. Another such drawable is used as selector for the grid view:

padded_border_normal.xml:

```
<item android:left="3dp"
      android:right="3dp"
      android:top="3dp"
      android:bottom="3dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke android:color="#8033b5e5" android:width="@dimen/border_width"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
        <size android:height="60dp" android:width="60dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

padded_border_pressed.xml:

```
<item android:left="3dp"
      android:right="3dp"
      android:top="3dp"
      android:bottom="3dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#6033b5e5" />
        <stroke android:color="#8033b5e5" android:width="@dimen/border_width"/>
        <corners android:radius="7dp"/>
        <size android:height="60dp" android:width="60dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

`grid.setSelector(R.drawable.padded_border_pressed);` when creating grid and `result.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.padded_border_normal);` when creating a view for grid list

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already got your answer.  Remove any spacing from the `GridView` and set the padding in each of your `ImageView`s to keep the look you want, but not actually have any spacing between cells.  You say you had to override `onMeasure()`, I'm not really sure why you had to do that from what you've said above.  Just set the `ImageView` for the width to be the same as the `GridView` cell and then set `height=width` and you may want to set the scaling of the `ImageView` to `centerInside`.

Comment: If just set padding, background will still be stretched to full size.

Comment: What are you referring to as background? The image background or the `GridView` background? I suggest setting the `GridView` background to a solid color (or just leave it at its default). Can you maybe take a screenshot?

Comment: Image background. Screenshot: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/15473231/reminder/ribbons.png

Comment: I think you just need to play with the scaling options (for the ImageView) to find the one that will work for you, to prevent stretching--did you try `centerInside`?

Comment: It only controls image, not ImageView's background. I might try having padding built-in into my background drawable though.

Comment: If they are defined at compile time, i.e. by using `R.drawable.my_bg`, or runtime by using `setImageResource(R.drawable.my_bg)`, then you can just convert them to 9 patch drawables and you won't have to worry about the stretching. Here's the reference to make them 9-patch: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: That would require a separate 9-patch for each color and each stroke width I need.